# stereo_image_proc error in hydro - error while loading shared libraries: libimage_proc.so

Tags: stere-image-proc, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using DRCSim on hydro and when roslaunching atlas.launch this error appears:

```
    opt/ros/hydro/lib/stereo_image_proc/stereo_image_proc: error while loading shared libraries: libimage_proc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
failed to start local process: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/stereo_image_proc/stereo_image_proc __name:=stereo_proc __log:=/home/gustavo/.ros/log/eca8b864-fb95-11e2-b1fd-001e65d8adfa/multisense_sl-camera-stereo_proc-6.log
local launch of stereo_image_proc/stereo_image_proc failed
[multisense_sl/camera/stereo_proc-6] process has died [pid -1, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/stereo_image_proc/stereo_image_proc __name:=stereo_proc __log:=/home/gustavo/.ros/log/eca8b864-fb95-11e2-b1fd-001e65d8adfa/multisense_sl-camera-stereo_proc-6.log].
log file: /home/gustavo/.ros/log/eca8b864-fb95-11e2-b1fd-001e65d8adfa/multisense_sl-camera-stereo_proc-6*.log
```

what can I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70801/stereo_image_proc-error-in-hydro---error-while-loading-shared-libraries:-libimage_proc.so/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 756 on 2013-08-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-08-03**:
Did you build the image_proc package?

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-08-03**:
No, I installed from apt-get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please try to install "ros-hydro-image-proc".

If that helps it looks like a missing run dependency in stereo_image_proc. I have filled a ticket for that: https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues/39

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-08-03**:
Ok, I will try it..

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-08-03**:
That works!! Thanks

**Comment by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) on 2013-08-04**:
That got fixed upstream, thx